# How to compute a "grand mean" in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to compute a grand mean in R.

lets say I had some data like this

```
 mean1     mean2     fire1    fire2
 1         1         2        3 
 2         2         3        4
 3         3         4        5
```

If I wanted to find the grand mean of that dataset is there a function that might handle it or do I need to do it the old fashion way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean(c(mean.default(dataset[[1]]), mean.default(dataset[[2]])))`

where in `c()` you have one `mean.default(dataset[[n]])` for each `n` in the range `n=1` to `n = [number of columns to be used in calculation]`